# Copy files between servers using SCP in ansible?

Tags: docker, ansible, devops, scp

I have executed a ansible script on my machine. What is does is

1.Copy a file from my machine to a docker container running on a remote machine

```
file.pb
```

2.Execute a command on docker container. That command uses the copied file & sign it.

**This is the command**

```
peer channel signconfigtx -f file.pb
```

Now i want to again copy this signed file to another machine after it is signed in the same ansible script from the docker container where it is now.

I want try `SCP` but not sure how it will work because it will ask for password.

Can anyone suggest me how can i do this ?

EDIT:

I tried on my local machine to fetch files from remote server but it i get below error

> fatal: [user1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unable to create local
>   directories(/home/dhiraj/ansible_practise/playlist/fetched/user1/home/user1/Documents/Blockchain/network/scripts):
>   [Errno 20] Not a directory:
>   '/home/dhiraj/ansible_practise/playlist/fetched/user1'"}

below is my ansible script

```
 - name:  Fetching a file from remote server
      fetch:
        src: "/home/user1/Documents/Blockchain/network/scripts/file.pb"
        dest: fetched
```

Comment: SCP wouldn’t ask for a password if you configure passwordless key authentication to the host.

Comment: run `mkdir fetched` to create dest `dest: fetched`. Do you want to `scp files to / from` docker container running in which machine? same `ansible server` or `remote machine`? What is the `docker image` which is running? You will need ssh server in that image. Please update the question with these details. However, I would suggest to use a `persistent volume` in the host machine (where docker container runs) and use it, instead of complicating.

Comment: Already created 'fetched' folder. docker container is running on remote machine & i am able to access it. I am able to access the directory which is mounted to docker container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of copying files directly bertween servers what i have done is i used `fetch` module of ansible. In fetch i just had to define `source path` and `destination path`.

Here is sample

```
   - name:  Fetching a file from remote server
      fetch:
        src: "{{ DEST }}/Documents/Blockchain/network/scripts/file.pb"
        dest: /home/fetched/
        flat: yes // it will not create dir strcuture as same as source
        validate_checksum: false
```

Comment: Note that the `dest` path _must be a directory_ and the path _must_ end with a directory separator ('/' on 'nix systems) or the `flat` attribute won't work.

Answer (score 1):

There are more options.

1) **scp from docker to another machine**

- Put public key of the user running scp at Docker to authorized_key of the user you connect at another machine.
- At docker run [command](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/command_module.html#command-execute-commands-on-targets): scp file.pb user@another_machine:file.pdb

2) **fetch and copy**

- [fetch](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/fetch_module.html#fetch-fetch-files-from-remote-nodes) from docker to your machine
- [copy](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/copy_module.html#copy-copy-files-to-remote-locations) from your machine to another machine

3) **fetch and pull**

- [fetch](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/fetch_module.html#fetch-fetch-files-from-remote-nodes) from docker to your machine
- At another machine run [ansible-pull](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/ansible-pull.html#ansible-pull) and run the playbook that would fetch the file from your machine.

4) Run scp at another machine ...